# Excel having columns with dot(.)

Tags: c#, excel

I am working in c# windows forms product.
I am exporting some data to an excel.these data are inputted by the user.the rows in he dataset are made columns in the excel.these column names has 'dot'. While exporting,these columns remain the same.But while trying to import back the data,the column names which are having dot will have # in the dataset
eg..initially it was A.B,now in dataset it is A#B.
on the client side i cannot simply convert # to dot as the user can also give input with #.Please help me to solve this problem.I am not able to find a solution.
Thanks
Neethu

Comment: how you are assigning data to `dataset`? it would be better, if you provide some related code.

Comment: is it maybe related to your practice of not leaving a space after the dots, e.i. you write `phrase0.phrase1`, instead of `phrase0. phrase1`

Comment: I am reading the excel using OLEDB and retrieving the data in the dataset.Column names having dot will be having # instaed of dot in the columns of dataset.

Comment: the headers of excel have the dot.the headers in excel bcoms columns in dataset.this is wer the issues com

Answer (score 3):

On your `connectionString`, set `HDR=No`. Now `DataSet` treats column names as rows and you will get the data as it is there in the `excel`.

```
string cnnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"C:\\Untitled 1.xls\";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\"";
```

Comment: Thank you KNVN,this worked out for me.Although i have to make some considerable changes as my initialy coding was done with the header name,i think i can deal with it...thanks a lot